# Unhandled exception get more information

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception

When the unhandled exception occurs I would like to know the line and source that fired the event.
I can usually get that throug

```
    var st = new StackTrace(e, true);
// Get the top stack frame
var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
// Get the line number from the stack frame
var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

but here it says that the exception type is different.
What's more I afraid that even if it worked it would report the line where the above code is and not the line that fired the event.

Comment: Add an exception handler and log it. SImply calling `Exception.ToString()` will return all the information you are trying to extract in this snippet and more

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to extract is already available by calling [Exception.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

From the documentation :

> The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class that threw the current exception, the message, the result of calling ToString on the inner exception, and the result of calling Environment.StackTrace. If any of these members is null, its value is not included in the returned string.

Comment: not sure that you got what I want. When an UNHANDLED exception occurs in source xxxx.cs I want to know where the error occurs in source yyyy.cs at line zzzz

Comment: All that appears in the string returned by `Exception.ToString()`. Just try it. Trying to extract the same information again is an expensive operation. To get the line number though, you need to deploy debug symbols together with your executable otherwise the runtime code has no idea what operation corresponded to which line. In fact ... there is a duplicate question that explains this